# How to post multipart/formdata using fetch in react-native?

Tags: fetch, react-native

[image: reference Image: Postman form]

i want to post Form Data like that.

what should i prepare for sending image file data?

i have Uri, type, filename, size.

then will use fetch for it.

Content-type in header is 'multipart/formdata'

thanks for helping

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing. Any luck?

Comment: sorry for late reply, my solution was just put this with other form-data altogether          postData.append('webmailAttachment',{
            uri:res.uri,
            type:res.type,
            name:res.fileName
          });

Comment: Can anyone look at this [doubt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54778655/7622297) and give me some suggestion

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should have an upload function, which should look like this:

```
upload(url, data) {
  let options = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    method: 'POST'
  };

  options.body = new FormData();
  for (let key in data) {
    options.body.append(key, data[key]);
  }

  return fetch(requestUrl, options)
      .then(response => {
        return response.json()
          .then(responseJson => {
            //You put some checks here
            return responseJson;
          });
      });
}
```

And you call it this way, sending the image blob path:

```
this.upload('http://exampleurl.com/someApiCall', {
  file: {
    uri: image.path,
    type: image.mime,
    name: image.name,
  }
}).then(r => {
  //do something with `r`
});
```

Comment: you should add the `await` at the `fetch` call in order to simplify the snippet. By other way, there would no reason to mark as "async" the function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of `FormData` and pass that as the body to fetch, like so:

```
const data = new FormData()
data.append("something", something)

fetch(url, { method: 'POST', body: form })
```

Comment: they required Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA should i put some specific code for boundary??

Answer (score 0):

### React Native code

```
fetch("url" ,{

    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },

    method:'POST',

    body: JSON.stringify(this.state.imageholder)

}).catch(function(error) {

console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);

throw error;

});
```

### Spring boot code

```
 @PostMapping(value="/",consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 public ResponseEntity<?> saveCustomerOrder(@RequestBody String[] file) throws SerialException, SQLException {

    TestImg imgObj=null;

    for (String img : file) {
        imgObj=new TestImg();
        byte[] decodedByte = Base64.getDecoder().decode(img);
        Blob b = new SerialBlob(decodedByte);
        imgObj.setImg(b);
        testRepo.save(imgObj);

    }
```