# After using Fetch I still Got Multipart Boundary in react.js when send formData

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multipartform-data

I seriously confused how to solve this multipart boundary when using Axios, react.js and multipart/formdata. I already stuck for 2 weeks to try to solve this but I feel like I getting closer to solved it but it still stuck no matter what solution I try.

I read and trysome solution from this topic:

[how-to-post-multipart-formdata-using-fetch-in-react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49625572/how-to-post-multipart-formdata-using-fetch-in-react-native)

[how-to-send-multipart-form-data-with-antd-upload-react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51697944/how-to-send-multipart-form-data-with-antd-upload-react)

[how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-from-react-js-with-an-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47168659/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-from-react-js-with-an-image)

this is my `create Order` function in `orderAction.js` :

```
function createOrder(data) {
    return dispatch => {
        let apiEndpoint = 'order';
        let payload = new FormData();
        // payload.append('orderImage', data.orderImage);

        // console.log("Cek Image : ", data.orderImage);
        for (const file of data.orderImage) {
            payload.append('orderImage', file)
        }

        payload.append('userId', data.userId);
        payload.append('materialId', data.materialId);
        // payload.append('materialId', '5d79930c8c4a882f44b1b0fb');
        payload.append('color', data.color);
        payload.append('description', data.description);
        payload.append('quantity', data.quantity);
        payload.append('city', data.city);
        payload.append('detailAddress', data.detailAddress);

        console.log("Cek Data : ", payload);

        fetch(config.baseUrl + apiEndpoint, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'),
                'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryHl8DZV3dBSj0qBVe'
            },
            body: payload
        })
        // orderService.post(apiEndpoint, payload)
        //     .then(res => {
        //         if(res.data.status === 200) {
        //             alert(res.data.Message);
        //             dispatch(createOrderSuccess(res.data));
        //             history.push('/user-order');
        //         } else {
        //             dispatch(createOrderFailed());
        //             alert(res.data.Message);
        //         }
        //     })
    };
}
```

can someone help me to solve this? I'm quite confused with this problem

**Edit 1**
after try using @narasimha solution finally I got rid the multipart boundary but I got weird behaviour where The data succesfully got encoded like this:

[image: You can see the Base64 image finally encoded in headers]

but When I trying check the response the photoUrl return `null` or `` like this:

[image: You can see photoUrl return null array]

and when I try using insomnia or postman it successfully generated the photoUrl like this:

[image: You can see at photoUrl array it return the imageurl]

where did I wrong in here?

Comment: could you solve this? I am currently facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem yesterday. The problem was with content type. I had used the same content type header as you are using. The thing is I removed content type and allowed the fetch () API to handle it automatically. It worked!!

Comment: Thankyou for the response, when I try using your solution finally i can get rid the boundary but photoUrl return null array as you can see in my `Edit 1` section